# Google Maps street view slow performance on IE8

Tags: javascript, google-maps, extjs, internet-explorer-8, google-street-view

We are embedding a Google Maps street view in our OpenLayers / ExtJS application. For all the browsers, it seems quite fast, except for IE8, specially in slower workstations, where it gets slow and the panning is not smooth at all.

So, using IE8, we go to maps.google.com , ask for a street view, it works fine. Same machine, IE8, go to our ExtJS application and ask for a street view, it is not that smooth, much slower. Same machine, Firefox (or even IE9), it is smooth enough.

Some thoughts :

- Having a look with Firebug and Fiddler it seems that the images are properly cached. So it doesn't seem that we are asking for too many requests. I mean, panning is still slow even if we don't perform any image request at all.
- maps.google.com does not need to authenticate as our app does, but for the previous reason, I would not think that is the problem.
- It is slow no matter we remove additional markers or the map including the pegman besides.
- This happens even if the window size is not too big. That is, smaller than the window we use for testing with maps.google.com
- I can see a CPU usage when panning of roughly 30% using street view in our application and 15% with maps.google.com

The code we use is not very different from the example :

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/streetview-simple

Any idea will be appreciated. Thanks.

Update. To simplify the problem, I tried getting rid of ExtJS. So I just open another window with the simple HTML below. Even that way, its performance is worse than just going to maps.google.com .

```
<html><head><meta charset='utf-8'><title>Street View controls</title><style> html, body, #map-canvas { height: 100%; margin: 0px; padding: 0px } </style> <script type='text/javascript' src='https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false'></script><script> function initialize() { var fenway = new google.maps.LatLng(51.48661637238365,-0.18295272897127387); var panoOptions = { position: fenway,  addressControlOptions: { position: google.maps.ControlPosition.BOTTOM_CENTER  },  linksControl: false,   panControl: false,  zoomControlOptions: {    style: google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.SMALL  }, enableCloseButton: false}; var panorama = new google.maps.StreetViewPanorama(      document.getElementById("map-canvas"), panoOptions);}google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);    </script>  </head>  <body>   <div id="map-canvas"></div </body></html>
```